# How can I have stable nick in Irssi?

Tags: irssi

Every time I'm connecting to the server due to the `screen irssi` command, I gain new nick with underline (like: `nick_` and now it's already `nick____`).

I don't have to say how annoying it is.
I tried to use command `screen -Ur irssi`, but then "There is no screen to be resumed matching irssi." appeared.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. It's very hard to help you debug a verbal description. Do you have code that you've written (even if it's not working)? please edit your question and add the code in so we can see it too (don't use the comments, the formatting is awful).

Comment: But there is no code. The problem is just in connecting to IRC always with new nick.

Comment: Ah, if there'e no code, then it's probably not really classified under "programming" (which is the bailiwick of Stack Overflow). Anything to do with running applications on a computer is more likely to fit better with our sister site ServerFault - which helps people with these kinds of issues instead :) I'll put in a "flag to close" that recommends moving the question there. Alternatively you might also find better help on SuperUser which is on running programs, but I think this is probably more ServerFault's area of expertise.

Comment: There's code now, in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77120607/22330192) below. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start *irssi* and enter these lines:

```
/network add -autosendcmd "/nick {your nick}" {server name}
/save
```

In these lines you might notice two "variables":

1. `{your nick}` - change to your *nick*;
2. `{server name}` - server's name (i.e. Freenode).

This sets Irssi to change your nick automatically (it runs a command after connection).

Also, you might like checking out Irssi documentation related to the subject: [documentation](https://irssi.org/documentation/settings/#server)

> `alternate_nick`
> An alternate nickname to use if your preferred one is already taken.

> `nick` `$IRCNICK`
> Your main, preferred nick.

Related: [resource](https://superuser.com/a/709662/570332)

Comment: This may actually not work, depending on the IRC network and its server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was also bothered by having my nickname sometimes changed into `nickname_`, but I wanted to observe that in the `irssi`'s status window and act manually, instead of setting up some automated nickname updates.

Thus, I implemented new `/NICKALL` alias that lists the current nicknames on all servers that are currently configured, displaying the good nicknames in **green,** and the bad, unexpected nicknames in **red.**  With this alias in place, observing the current nickname statuses becomes quite comfortable.

Here's the long, single line of code that needs to be added to the `~/.irssi/config` file, into the `aliases = { ... };` section:

`NICKALL = "SCRIPT EXEC my \\$expected = Irssi::settings_get_str(\"nick\")\\; foreach my \\$server (Irssi::servers()) { Irssi::print(\"Your nickname on \\$server->{tag} server \\$server->{address} is \" . ( (\\$server->{nick} eq \\$expected) ? \"\\\\033[1\\;32m\" : \"\\\\033[1\\;31m\" ) . \"\\$server->{nick}\\\\033[0m with user mode \\$server->{usermode}\")\\; }";`

Just to clarify, all of the code above goes into a single line.  Below is an example of the status window contents produced by executing the newly created `/NICKALL` alias, minus the already described green/red coloring of the nicknames that indicates their correctness.

```
Irssi: Your nickname on <network #1> server <server #1> is <nickname> with user mode irwxz
Irssi: Your nickname on <network #2> server <server #2> is <nickname> with user mode Ziw
Irssi: Your nickname on <network #3> server <server #3> is <nickname> with user mode Ri
```

Surprisingly, implementing this alias took me quite a lot of time, because I went first with a much simpler alias that didn't use Perl code.  Alas, there are some bugs in `irssi` that caused wrong nicknames to be displayed that way, which needed time to be debugged and tested.  Eventually, I had to whip up this Perl code, which I've tested to work as expected.

By the way, it's quite sad and annoying to see many minor bugs present in `irssi`.  The one mentioned above is just an example, unfortunately.

---

Here's an improved version of the `/NICKALL` alias, which handles currently disconnected servers properly, by emitting appropriate messages:

`NICKALL = "SCRIPT EXEC my \\$expected = Irssi::settings_get_str(\"nick\")\\; foreach my \\$server (Irssi::servers()) { if (\\$server->{connected}) { Irssi::print(\"Your nickname on \\$server->{tag} server \\$server->{address} is \" . ( (\\$server->{nick} eq \\$expected) ? \"\\\\033[1\\;32m\" : \"\\\\033[1\\;31m\" ) . \"\\$server->{nick}\\\\033[0m with user mode \\$server->{usermode}\")\\; } else { Irssi::print(\"You are currently \\\\033[1\\;31mnot connected\\\\033[0m to \\$server->{tag} server \\$server->{address}\")\\; } }";`

As a quick reminder, all of the code above must go into a single line in the `aliases = { ... };` section of the `~/.irssi/config` file.